# What does this mean? (wordPress)

Tags: wordpress

I'm using a plugin called custom post Type UI.  And when I go to Manage Post types, i'm getting a notice message.

"Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$publish in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/allisongrayce.com/wp-content/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/custom-post-type-ui.php on line 648"

Any Advice would be awesome

Thanks!

Plugin site: http://webdevstudios.com/plugin/custom-post-type-ui/
Version 0.8.2

My WordPress Version: 3.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means there is a bug in the plugin (an undefined variable or a variable that is not being properly defined). You would be able to get better help by posting a comment on the plugin download page or contact the developer in some other way so they can fix it.

Also make sure the plugin supports the version of WordPress that you are using.

Providing a link to the page where you got the plugin will also help us to better diagnose the problem directly (fix the bug).

Comment: Also it is Compatible up to: 3.9

Comment: I talked to the developers and got it worked out.  Thanks for the advice

Comment: No problem. I find it's always best to do that especially with code that is actively being developed. It helps the developer become aware of any issues that they may have missed.